# How to create a custom exception? This exception does not work

Tags: python

I deduce age:

```
def retrieve_age(person):
      try: 
        return int(person["age"])
      except ValueError: 
        print("You entered the age incorrectly")
      except int(person["age"])<=0:
        print("You entered a negative age") 
print(retrieve_age({"name" : "Max", "age": -5}))
```

Question:

```
except int(person["age"])<=0:
            print("You entered a negative age")
```

This does not work. How to create a custom exception against negative input?

Answer (score 1):

Python is an OOP language. so declare a class of your exception which inherits from class `exception` and do what ever you want in your new class exception:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ....
```

Then use it to raise your new exceptions (`MyException`):

```
raise MyException("MSG")
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative age in your example is logical error. You need to do the check yourself and then raise an exception. You can create custom exception as answered by Adam or simply raise default exception with your message.

```
if int(person["age"])<=0:
      raise Exception("You entered a negative age")
```